# Number of ordered pairs of $A,B$ in Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $|X|$ denote the number of elements in a set $X,$
>
> Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be a sample space,
>
> where each element is equally likely to occur.
>
> If $A$ and $B$ are independent events associated with
>   $S,$
>
> Then the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$
>
> such that $1 \leq |B| < |A|,$ equals

what i try

Let number of elements in $A,B,A \cap B$ is $x,y,z$ respectively

conditions given as $1\leq y\leq x.$

For $2$ Independent events $A,B$

is $\displaystyle P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)\Rightarrow \frac{z}{6}=\frac{x}{6}\cdot \frac{y}{6}\Rightarrow z=xy/6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Given condition is |A|>|B|  , A and B are independent events which gives total number of ordered pairs (A,B) = 422

Answer (score 4):

The equation
$$z=\frac{xy}{6}$$
shows that the events $A$ and $B$ can be independent only if

1. $A=S$, or
2. $|A|=3,|B|=2$
3. $|A|=4,|B|=3$

In the 2nd case $A$ and $B$ have 1 common element; in the 3rd case $A$ and $B$ have 2 common elements.

In the 1st case, we have $2^6-2$ solutions ($B$ can be anything except $S$ and $\varnothing$).

In the 2nd case, we can choose $A$ by $\binom{6}{3}$ ways and then $B$ by $3\cdot 3$ ways.

In the 3rd case we can choose common elements by $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, then 2 remaining A elements by $\binom{4}{2}$ ways and the remaining B element by 2 ways.

Summing it all
$$64-2+\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{6}\cdot 3 \cdot 3 + \frac{6\cdot 5}{2}\cdot \frac{4\cdot 3}{2}\cdot 2= 422$$

---

PS: thanks @karthikeya kurella for noticing the 3rd case.

Answer (score 3):

The condition should be $1\le y\lt x$, not $\le$.

Since $z=xy/6$, $x$ or $y$ must be divisible by $2$ and by $3$, and $xy\le6$. With $1\le y\lt x$, that allows only two solutions: $x=6$, $y=1$ and $x=3$, $y=2$.

In the first case, we have $6$ choices for the element in $y$.

In the second case we have $z=3\cdot2/6=1$, so there must be exactly one common element. That gives us $6$ choices for the common element, then $5$ choices for the other element in $y$ and then $\binom42=6$ choices for the other two elements in $x$.

Thus the total number of ordered pairs is $6+6\cdot5\cdot6=186$.